# Missing comma in SQL command for insert statement

Tags: sql

I have the following query for inserting values into my tutor table:

```
INSERT INTO Tutor ( tutor_ID NUMBER(3), 
                    F_name VARCHAR(14), 
                    L_name VARCHAR(13), 
                    Date_Joined DATE, 
                    Phone NUMBER(10), 
                    Email VARCHAR(30),
                    amount_of_allowance VARCHAR(5), 
                    tutoree_ID NUMBER(6)
                  ) VALUES
                  ( 610, 
                    'DAVID', 
                    'FOONG', 
                    '02/07/2007', 
                    02104465, 
                    'DAVIDFOONG@YAHOO.COM', 
                    '800', 
                    007);
```

after running it writes

```
"Error starting at line 28 in command:
INSERT INTO Tutor (tutor_ID NUMBER(3), F_name VARCHAR(14), L_name VARCHAR(13), Date_Joined DATE, Phone NUMBER(10), Email VARCHAR(30), amount_of_allowance VARCHAR(5), tutoree_ID NUMBER(6))
VALUES  (610, 'DAVID', 'FOONG', '02/07/2007', 02104465, 'DAVIDFOONG@YAHOO.COM', '800', 007)

Error at Command Line:28 Column:28
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:"
```

But I don't understand where I missed a comma?

Comment: Don't include the types for the fields (NUMBER(3), VARCVHAR(14), etc.).    Those are already known by the database and will cause the error, because of the unknown format there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not include datatype definitions in your insert statements:

```
insert into Tutor
(tutor_ID, F_name, L_name, Date_Joined, Phone, Email, amount_of_allowance, tutoree_ID)
values 
(610, 'DAVID', 'FOONG', '02/07/2007', 02104465, 'DAVIDFOONG@YAHOO.COM', '800', 007);
```

Comment: thnxs for helping me out, arigato